# Java: Too high value handling - best practice?

Tags: java, exception

This is both a specific and a fundamental question:

I am reading a value from a configuration file and it must be higher than some X or else I won;t be able to run my program correctly.

In case the value is lower than X...

1. Is it a correct practice to throw an exception in that case?
2. If yes - Should I use a predefined exception (and which one) or should I create my own exception class, and should I extend it from some other exception class?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Only if its critial for the rest of the program, else not (still inform user probably) 2. Depends on how critical it is and if there already exists an exception which would suite the error (in your case i don't think there is one except `RuntimeException` which should only be used is the error is critical)

Comment: Read the input, `if (input > x) throw new Exception("input greater than x");` ? Something like this?

Comment: This is a design decision which depends completely on your specific situation. You, as a designer, need to decide how severe such error is and whether there is any good way to recover from it.

Comment: The exception designed for such cases is the `IllegalArgumentException`, provided you have declared the range in the documentation of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a correct practice to throw an exception in that case?

Throwing an exception is a valid choice. Another valid choice would be to use some reasonable default value, and log a warning for the user explaining what has happened.

The choice depends on how sensitive is the value being configured. You have to make case-by-case decisions on this.

> Should I use a predefined exception (and which one) or should I create my own exception class, and should I extend it from some other exception class?

If you choose to throw an exception in favor of a default value, throw a custom exception derived from `Exception` to make it "checked". This would ensure that there is code to handle the exception in the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes
2.) Make your own one, named after the meaning of the value your loading. 
You can simply extend IllegalArgumentException or NumberFormatException.

The more precise you are the better - makes your code and behaviour of your application clearer.

If the value you are talking of is of central/outstanding meaning for the application i would extend NumberFormatException with a more precice one. If there are more values than just this one that do not have distinguishable meaning you can also simply use NumberFormatException instead of extending it.

Comment: But why ? This is just your opinion for the moment

Comment: He asks about "correct practice". This is correct practice. No need to argue about that. It's nice and clean and identifies the incident exactly.

Comment: @ospf it doesn't matter if it is generally accepted as correct practice, it is still valuable to explain why it is correct...